# Spring Boot - How to create entities and nested entities in single POST request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I’m trying to figure out specific thing with Spring Data, and that is: how to  create an entity and a related entity with one single POST request.

I can create related entities with separate requests, but with single request I’m not sure. (without creating a specific controller method to it). Example:

**ReusableComponent.java**

```
@Entity
public class ReusableComponent {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long id;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy="component", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       private List<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

       private String name;

       public Long getId() {
              return id;
       }
       public void setId(Long id) {
              this.id = id;
       }
       public List<Consumer> getConsumers() {
              return consumers;
       }
       public void setConsumers(List<Consumer> consumers) {
              this.consumers = consumers;
       }
       public String getName() {
              return name;
       }
       public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
       }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
@Entity
public class Consumer<ResuableComponent> {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long id;

    private String name;

       @ManyToOne(targetEntity=ReusableComponent.class)
       private ResuableComponent component;

       public Long getId() {
              return id;
       }
       public void setId(Long id) {
              this.id = id;
       }
       public ResuableComponent getComponent() {
              return component;
       }
       public void setComponent(ResuableComponent component) {
              this.component = component;
       }
       public String getName() {
              return name;
       }
       public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
       }
}
```

**ReusableComponentRepository.java**

```
public interface ReusableComponentRepository extends CrudRepository<ReusableComponent, Long> 
{
       Iterable<ReusableComponent> findAll();

       @RestResource(exported = false)
       List<ReusableComponent> findByName(String name);
}
```

**POST  http://localhost:8080/reusableComponents**

Request Body:

```
{ "name": "datagrid", "consumers": [{ "name": "financial app" }] }
```

**GET  http://localhost:8080/reusableComponents**

Response:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "reusableComponents": [
            {
                "consumers": [],
                "name": null,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/reusableComponents/1"
                    },
                    "reusableComponent": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/reusableComponents/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/reusableComponents"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/reusableComponents"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are no consumers in the reusableComponent instance.  I had this working before, but for the life of me I can’t figure it out now.

Comment: what you see here is the response. Check in your database. It might be saved. I don't see anything wrong in the above code

Comment: Hi pvpkiran, I checked the results afterwards by calling a GET request on http://localhost:8080/reusableComponents/1 - but the "consumers" property was just an empty array.

Comment: Specify FetchType for you consumers field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by removing the `mappedBy="component"` attribute in the @OneToMany decorator on the consumers property of the ReusableComponent entity, like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
```

The above works perfectly.